# Can I disable Driver Signature Enforcement on Windows 7 and 10 programatically

Tags: driver, signature

I have an EV certificate for signing drivers etc.

As of July 2021 however Microsoft has decided to stick their nose in and require all drivers (.sys etc) to be submitted to them for dual signing.
It is quite a task to do so and as of right now their partner website has a bug when creating a new account and this has been dragging on for the past 3 weeks.

Anyway my question here is, can I temporarily via a Registry change or whatever, disable the Driver Signature Enforcement process.

I did find one article that stated the following ;

```
Type the command: bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks on and then press Enter to run the command.
```

I do not want to use that method as it is manual and does not seem to work for me.

I also saw the following which I tried ;

```
2. Look for: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Wind ows NT\Driver Signing]
3. Change the BehaviorOnFailedVerify key value to "0" for ignore, "1" for getting just warning mesage and "2" to block completely.
```

This does not work either at all.

The only thing that works for me is to disable via the usual F8 process.

Has anyone had success or seen a way of disabling the Driver Signature Enforcement programatically ?
Is there a way of hooking into that F8 process perhaps whatever it happens to be doing ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with [DSE Patcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dse-patcher/)
It's in the bin folder, just click it, and click disable, you should be able to install your driver now.